# calculate percentage difference of two periods

Tags: javascript

I need to compare period 1 to period 2 and show the percentage between them. either one can also be 0. what would be the best way to calculate that?

```
const revenueCalc= (row.revenue-row.revenue2)/row.revenue
row.campaign.formattedName+=' '+ '|'+' '+'CHANGE OF'+' '+(revenueCalc).toFixed(1)+'%'
```

this code for example can return negative infinity and other wrong percentages.

Comment: I think your formula is not correct, maybe you are asking for this one ( rev1/rev2) *100

Comment: this formula gives infinity result

Comment: infinity seems correct if rev2 is 0.

Comment: cannot show as infinity so if rev=10 rev2 =0 should show -100%